# How to use SQLite data in R without loading data

Tags: database, r, sqlite

I am using `R Studio` for some data analysis. I have a 500MB `.csv` file. System specs: i5 + 4GB RAM. If I load the file in R, it takes up some 1.5GB of my RAM and I don't have enough RAM left for other operations. It gives errors like -

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.5MB

So, to save space, I decided to use `SQLite`. I stored my data in a SQLite database file. I want to know if there's a way I can do operations on the data without loading it in R. Using all those R functions directly on my SQLite database.

Comment: Use this package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html

Comment: There is also http://cran.r-project.org/package=ff

Comment: Your problem is strange to me cause I work with similar files and they don't use so much memory. More - 500MB (uncompressed) file shouldn't take more than 500MB memory.

Comment: @Marek I can't say how or why but it does take up a lot of memory. This process called RStudio R Session takes up some 1.3-1.5GB of memory. Any idea why?

Comment: @Macbook There is many reasons. I will start with separating reading data from analyzing it. First read csv file and save it as .RData (with `save`). Start fresh instance of RStudio and see it's better. You could check if there are columns you could get rid of and remove them (before `save`).

Comment: @Marek Thanks! This almost solved the problem. My original file size = 550MB, reading it in RStudio was taking up some 1.5GB of my memory. I saved it as .RData file, it got compressed to 178MB. But when I loaded the file back in RStudio, it's taking up some 780MB of my memory. 
So my RStudio is taking up a chunk of memory much much bigger than my data size. Any idea why it could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Using “all those R functions directly on [the] SQLite database” won't be possible, as access to a database isn't transparent. Almost all R functions expect their data to reside in memory, and won't be able to deal with indirection.

That said, you might be able to translate those R functions you need for your application into SQL queries. Then you could operate directly on the data in SQLite, without loading it first. In particular, you might be able to do perform some query which omits some columns, only queries one set of rows at a time, or combines several rows into one. The resulting data.frame would be smaller than the whole table, and might be enough for your application.

If everything else fails, you might want to consider using a 64bit R and an operating system configured to provide sufficient swap space. In such a setup, memory-intensive operations may still take rather long, and could make your system *really* slow while they are being performed. But they should succeed eventually, without such ugly error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am very new to both R and SQL.
"you might be able to translate those R functions you need for your application into SQL queries." How do I do this?

Comment: Depends on the functions, the layout of your data, and so on. Things like mean, variance and so on can be easily computed using the SQL query, using aggregating functions like `MEAN`, `SUM`, `COUNT`. But I wouldn't want to implement e.g. a principal component analysis in SQL. So it all depends on what you have to compute.